# flutter: showing no devices connected in android studio and vscode

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Android Studio or VsCode showing 'no devices ' connected. But in the logcat of Android Studio it's showing my device.
[image]

And by:

```
flutter doctor
```

is showing 2 devices 1 is my phone and another one emulator.
[image]

I also tried with:

```
flutter devices
```

and it's showing 2 devices connected.
[image]

And by manually using

```
flutter run - d 'device id' // tried on both phone and emulator
```

I can run successfully the app on the devices.
[image]

The problem is in Android Studio and VsCode not showing any devices.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2

---

#### Solved

Solved by using:

```
flutter config --android-sdk /path/android/sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me

1 be sure you that developer mode is active

2 be sure you that debugging mode is active too

3 the secret here: try to change the USB connection on the phone from MTP to PTP (some phones will work right here)

but the problem with me didn't finish here but I go back to MTP connection it solved, I don't know why it didn't work for the first MTP connection but it works.

Comment: devices are connected successfully  and from terminal i can also run apps on these devices . but the issue that these devices are no showing under IDE

Answer (score 0):

- it seems your machine is need to restart
- if your problem not solved download and setup this ADB driver :  http://dl.adbdriver.com/upload/adbdriver.zip
- if not solved yet try replace your platform tools folder which is located in your android sdk path by this folder : https://www.mediafire.com/file/g1e2a7npgfk40x5/platform-tools.rar/file

Comment: i am using Ubuntu and you referred me a .exe installer :/

Comment: Problem is sloved by using  flutter config --android-sdk /path/andriod/sdk